# Simpler way to judge nil value in (if)?

Tags: if-statement, clojure

I often write like the following:

```
(if (nil? a-value) another-value a-value)
```

is there a simpler function available like:

```
(if-nil? a-value another-value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a default value, then the usual idiom is to use the `or` macro:

```
(or foo default-value)
```

Which will return `default-value` when `foo` is falsey (nil or false), or `foo` whenener `foo` is truthy (i.e. any non-nil value except `false`).

You can typically also use [`if-not`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/if-not) in such circumstances, since nil is considered to be false. Of course, you need to watch out for actual `false` values, since these will be treated the same as nil.

As a final option, you can always use a macro to get exactly the `if-nil?` behaviour you are looking for:

```
(defmacro if-nil? 
  ([a b] (if-nil? a b nil))
  ([a b c]
    `(if (nil? ~a) ~b ~c)))
```

Comment: Note that you need to be careful with this solution if false is a valid value for foo.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply define an `if-nil?` macro:

```
(defmacro if-nil? [expr body] 
  `(let [e# ~expr] 
    (if (nil? e#) ~body e#)))
```

Comment: Beware the double evaluation: `(let [e# ~expr] (if (nil? e#) ~body e#))`

Comment: You're absolutely right, of course. I got carried away by the simplicity of the example given in the question. Thanks!